# How do I compare each table data with the remaining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, union, tableau-api, outer-join

[Example input and Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlVya.png)
I have multiple Tables like mentioned in the picture. Each table represents opportunities on each day. My task is to compare the opportunities on the Table1 with Table 2 and Table 3. Table 2 with Table 3 and so on for multiple tables.
Usually when I compare 1 table with other I will do a FULL OUTER JOIN and get the comparison via TABLEAU report. This works well In case of 1 comparison. But the issue that I am facing now is I may have so many tables in this way and all needs to be compared with each other
Example:
Jan1 table should be compared with Jan2 Table, Jan3 Table, Jan4 table so..on
Jan2 table should be compared with Jan3 Table, Jan4 Table, Jan5 table so..on

Please suggest if there is a way to compare these tables with out having to outer join each and every combination of tables.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have multiple tables? It would be much easier having a single one with an extra `DATE` column.

Comment: Each is a snapshot of opportunities taken every day. and Yes these can be combined in a single one with extra DATE column. My question now is how do I compare  changes (example: Stage Change,$$ Change etc) for each opportunity which are in 1st DATE snapshot with the same opportunity in the 2nd DATE snapshot

Comment: @Rajashree . . . What do YOU mean by "compare"?  Please provide desired results.  Code for "comparing" two tables would also help others understand what you mean.

Comment: Start by fixing your broken schema

Comment: @Gordon I have edited the picture that I have uploaded earlier, Please review and let me know if it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The full join technique also works to compare more than two table.

However MySQL does not support it, so you could go for `union all`:

```
select
    id,
    name,
    price,
    max(who = 't1') is_in_table1,
    max(who = 't2') is_in_table2,
    max(who = 't3') is_in_table3
from (
    select id, name, price, 't1' who from table1
    union all select id, name, price, 't2' who from table2
    union all select id, name, price, 't3' who from table3
) t
group by id, name, price
```

This gives you one row for each distinct row available in the originating three tables, with 3 boolean flags indicating whether that row was found in each table.

Comment: @Rajashree . . . I think this answers your question.